# Whats up with the favicons?

Tags: bug, status-completed

Aviation SE has multiple favicons.

- One is visible in chat [image]
- The other is visible everywhere else [image]

So, does everybody get two now?

Comment: cache is a crazy thing

Answer (score 1):

It looks like we do currently have 2 --  <s>https://aviation.stackexchange.com/favicon.ico has reverted to the "A", and</s>(Nevermind.... 's the new one when I use wget. *caching.*) the [Twitter account](https://twitter.com/stackaviation) never changed AFAIK.

Most places should have the airplane icon though:
[image: Stack Exchange main site]

Comment: I am seeing the "A" everywhere, other than chat.

Comment: I'm going to blame cache 'cuz its the most likely suspect -- in fact I blame cache for thinking the favicon reverted (I just pulled it with `wget` and it's the airplane icon)

Comment: I updated the Twitter account with the new image. It looks like one of the files we use for icons didn't get updated, so I'm gonna need to bug a designer for that.